# Convert if else condition with "dot" in SAS to R

Tags: r, sas

I have this code in SAS. I am new to SAS and do not have much experience with it. I tried to convert this SAS code into R, but I am not sure about the lines indicated as "Not sure". Can someone please help me figure out the R equivalent of this bit of code?

```
mvpawk=(wmpa)+(wvpa*2); if mvpawk>2520 then mvpawk=2520; /*cap six hours per day*/
mets=mvpawk*3;
if . < mvpawk <150 then meetcdc=0; # Not sure
else if mvpawk >=150 then meetcdc=1;
if nopa in (.,1) and ltpa in (.,2) and mvpawk=0 then sedentary=1; # Not sure
else if nopa=2 or ltpa=1 or mvpawk > 0 then sedentary=0;
```

My attempt to R code:

```
lifestyle$mvpawk <- lifestyle$wmpa + (lifestyle$wvpa *2)
lifestyle$mvpawk[which(lifestyle$mvpawk > 2520)] <- 2520
lifestyle$meetcdc <- ifelse(lifestyle$mvpawk < 150, 0,1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` in SAS is missing, similar to null, but it has the characteristic of a number - the most extreme negative number.  So `. < x < some number` is a way of saying that `x` is less than some number but also not missing (null).  In R, that's not a consideration you need to make, null is not 'less than' a number.  So here you can just ignore the null and just say `mvpawk < 150`.

Comment: Thank you, what about this `if nopa in (.,1)` part?

Comment: Similar - that is `if nopa is null or 1`.

Comment: To read this in English: if (answer to No Physical Activity? is 1  (Yes) or not answered) and (answer to Light Physical Activity? is 2 (No) or not answered) and (amount of physical activity per week is none (zero)) then (person is sedentary).